# Setting for echoing php in html

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to make an existing php project work on my localhost, but there is a line of code that breaks the whole app:

`<a href="javascript:function(<?echo "$id1";?>)">`

In the app I see the output `)">`. So that there must be something wrong with the way the php var is echoed into the `<a>`

On the remote Server the code works fine, so this must be a missing setting on my localhost.

**Localhost:**
XAMPP
PHP Version 5.6.23
default_charset: ISO-8859-1

**Server**
PHP Version 5.6.29-0+deb8u1
default_charset: ISO-8859-1

Do you have any idea what setting could lead to this behaviour?

PS: Please no discussion about whether this is good coding style or not. Unfortunately I can't change this because it's not my project and there are a lot of lines like this.

Comment: im betting on short tags not on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should enable short_open_tag `<? ?>`

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag